# mysql translation tables with missing language fallback

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have a database structure like this:

> Countries

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_5D66EBAD77153098` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

> Countries Language

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `country_languages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `language_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_1532561982F1BAF4` (`language_id`),
  KEY `IDX_15325619F92F3E70` (`country_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

> Language

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `languages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `iso` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `is_primary` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_A0D153795E237E06` (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_A0D1537961587F41` (`iso`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And the data for languages table:

```
id    name        iso
----------------------
1     English     en
2     German      de
3     Italian     it
```

And country table:

```
id    code
----------------
1     ie
```

And country languages table

```
id    country_id    language_id    name
----------------------------------------------
1     1             1              Ireland in English
2     1             2              Ireland in German
```

I am trying to write a query that will return the following result in order to be able to display it. (if possible)

```
(Language)          (Country name)
English             Ireland in English
German              Ireland in German
Italian             #NULL OR EMPTY STRING
```

And second I am trying to understand if it is possible to set for example english as the default language and when content for language with id 3 (Italian) is not present the default should fallback in as a result like this:

```
(Language)          (Country name)
English             Ireland in English
German              Ireland in German
Italian             Ireland in English #please note language id is 3 -> Italian.
```

Comment: I'm confused by your example. the "country languages table", is that actually a table or is that the result of a query? Also the queries right after, it's just not clear what "id" is supposed to mean and how those data come together...

Comment: @Jakumi I have updated my question. I hope now it's more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay, so the following query can probably be done without a subquery but with a join instead. I'd trust the query optimizer does this, but I wouldn't be too sure.

```
SELECT l.name as language,
       (SELECT cl.name 
        FROM country_languages cl 
        WHERE cl.country_id=[the wanted country id]
        ORDER BY cl.language_id=l.id DESC,
                 cl.language_id=1 DESC
        LIMIT 1) as country_name
FROM languages l
```

In this version language_id 1 is used as the prefered fallback, you could probably add more languages in a similar manner. Using `FIND_IN_SET` instead as a second order criterion would work as well (`FIND_IN_SET(cl.language_id,'1,2,3') DESC` or whatever order you'd prefer).

Of course this query right now is for a fixed country_id. It could be extended in a similar manner for multiple countries with another join:

```
SELECT l.name as language,
       (SELECT cl.name 
        FROM country_languages cl 
        WHERE cl.country_id=c.id 
        ORDER BY cl.language_id=l.id DESC,
                 cl.language_id=1 DESC
        LIMIT 1) as country_name
FROM countries c
JOIN languages l
```

an alternative to subqueries would be to join the country_languages twice, and just select the first one not being null (which is probably one of the cleaner solutions):

```
SELECT l.name as language, 
       COALESCE(first.name, second.name) as country_name
FROM countries c
JOIN languages l
LEFT JOIN country_languages first ON 
        (first.country_id=c.id AND first.language_id=l.id)
LEFT JOIN country_languages second ON
        (second.country_id=c.id AND second.language_id=1)
```

If language id 1 is your fallback language. This can be expanded as well to provide multiple fallback languages ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Did not notice that the default value should be not for all countries...

Comment: One comment. Because I use `Symfony` and `Doctrine` instead of `IFNULL`  `COALESCE` should be used. For the `IFNULL` people should write a `DoctrineExtension` class.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the query for first part using joins:

```
SELECT `country_languages`.id, `country_languages`.country_id,`country_languages`.language_id, `country_languages`.name  FROM `countries` left join country_languages on `countries`.id=`country_languages`.`country_id`
```

You can declare a status column in countries languages table and set status as 0,1,2 to mark priority as to how they will be fetched.